# Compiling a CWEB program from Knuth

Tags: c

I downloaded a CWEB program from Don Knuth — specifically
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/sliding.w.
I converted the `sliding.w` to `sliding.c`.
Now I'm trying to compile it using:

> gcc sliding.c -o sliding

But then I get:

```
./sliding.w:116:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 ^
/tmp/cc9NVnXq.o: In function `main':
sliding.c:(.text+0x2006): undefined reference to `gb_init_rand'
sliding.c:(.text+0x201c): undefined reference to `gb_fptr'
sliding.c:(.text+0x202b): undefined reference to `gb_fptr'
sliding.c:(.text+0x2036): undefined reference to `gb_fptr'
sliding.c:(.text+0x2047): undefined reference to `gb_flip_cycle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to link whatever `gb_flip.h` corresponds to.

Comment: The compiler warning means that the generated code is for C90 and not for C99 or C11 (but your C compiler — GCC — defaults to C11 mode, so the warning is required).  The return type of `main()` is `int`, but since C99, you've been required to state as much.  Look in the `sliding.w` file; is the code there written without the `int`?  If so, fix it.  If not, you'll have to find out where the definition of `main()` came from. (However, a quick look at `sliding.w` shows that it omits the `int` from `main()` — it needs to be updated for modern C.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is just a warning.  The fatal error is you are missing the `gb_` symbols, which are defined here:

http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/sgb/gb_flip.w

So first you need to compile gb_flip.w into a .c file, then compile both .c files together like this:

```
gcc sliding.c gb_flip.c -o sliding
```

Comment: 'Just a warning' — yes, but warnings should not be ignored.